# Word documents create, open and edit within web application - PHP

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework, ms-word, editor

Want know any external API web service or PHP libraries that will allow me to open, edit and save word documents within my  web application i’m implementing using a editor.

Basically I want something like  Google docs or Zoho or shutterb offer, I know Google offer Gdata API (Zend Framework) but this requires users to have account with them.

I researched found PHP COM libraries allow use to create word document but I need a editor maybe something like tinyMCE or ckeditor.

Other I researched but do not meet my requirements, these included:
Crocodoc
Ulteo
Gopc
office365
teamlab.

can OpenOffice be integrated once its installed on the server?

Anyone with suggestion or alternative methods?

Comment: Loading and rendering properly in HTML and making it editable and then *saving it all back* is a major challenge. This is what Google do with Docs... I don't think it's something that a lone developer can do at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open/Libre Office can be integrated with PHP applications using the The Open Office alternative to COM ([PUNO](http://www.wstech2.net/index.php?do=0a,01,05)) (requires Open Office installed on the server with Java support enabled), but you'll still need an editor of some kind if you want to allow online users to edit documents via a browser.

Comment: Yeah. He would need an editor that translates *any* document into HTML, while retaining all the Office-specific stuff like TOCs, headings... and then after editing, wraps it all up, and stores it as an office document again. That's a really tall order.

Comment: Yeah, amazing how many people hope/expect that an office document API will come complete with a cross-platform editor as well (especially when they're after something for free)

Comment: @MarkBaker Libre Office looks handy in the future when they launch web version. But i still curious how google doc works.